# Bitcoins with several laptops with no electricity cost. Is it profitable?

Tags: miner-configuration

English is not my mother language, so excuse me for any mistakes.

My Job is to test laptops for reselling in the outlet market. Between me and my collegues we test an average of 16 laptops per day.(And they stay there for the night too).

The catch is: After 24h we must format and close them and replace them for new others.

We were wondering if we could use them to mine, given the fact that the laptops are always being replaced i don't know how to do it or even if it's possible.

Many thanks,
pmleal

Comment: Short answer: no.  We all know that "free" electricity just means that someone else is paying, but even when you take theft into consideration, the profits wouldn't be worth the setup time.  Check the duplicate question for details.

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of several laptops, and setting so many PC's that are not designed for this kind of work, and be set on fire after a day working. Why not consider taking some 
 Acalon or Antminer R4, or something that is worth it. 
 However using electricity is never a good idea, it is not cost efficient to mine on electricity. 
 You can buy a bike instead :) and produce it yourself. Just a joke, there are different cheaper ways to make it work.